# How to put my pdf in Mail atachment

Tags: c#

i need a help with a code to make a atachment of my .pdf file to email.
I tried to find a solution but i can´t find one.
Sorry for my bad english

Here is my pdf creating code

```
SaveFileDialog dialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
            dialog1.Title = "Saving pdf ";
            dialog1.Filter = "PDF Files (*.pdf)|*.pdf|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            dialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
            if (dialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(dialog1.FileName);
            }
           /*  DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
             if (result == DialogResult.OK)
             {
                 string caminho = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
                 var pasta2 = caminho.Replace(@"\", @"\\");*/
                 Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 10, 10, 42, 35);
                 PdfWriter writertest = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(dialog1.FileName, FileMode.Create));
                 doc.Open();
                 PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(itemDataGridView.Columns.Count);
                 for (int j = 0; j < itemDataGridView.Columns.Count; j++)
                 {
                     table.AddCell(new Phrase(itemDataGridView.Columns[j].HeaderText));
                 }
                 table.HeaderRows = 1;
                 for (int i = 0; i < itemDataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
                 {
                     for (int k = 0; k < itemDataGridView.Columns.Count; k++)
                     {
                         if (itemDataGridView[k, i].Value != null)
                         {
                             table.AddCell(new Phrase(itemDataGridView[k, i].Value.ToString()));
                         }
                     }
                 }
                 doc.Add(table);
                 doc.Close();
```

Here is my email sending code

```
 Pesquisar_Items pesquisar = new Pesquisar_Items();
            var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 25);
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("josepedrobrito@hotmail.com", "*******");
            var mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new MailAddress("josepedrobrito@hotmail.com");
            mail.To.Add(textBox1.Text);
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.Subject = textBox2.Text;
            string mailBody = "<table width='100%' style='border:Solid 1px Black;'>"; ;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in itemDataGridView.Rows)
            {
                mailBody += "<tr>";
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    mailBody += "<td>" + cell.Value + "</td>";
                }
                mailBody += "</tr>";
            }
            mailBody += "</table>";
            client.Send(mail);
            MessageBox.Show("O email send ");
            this.Close();
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.attachments.aspx

Comment: That i know , i already saw this, but i can´t implement in my code...

Comment: You're not actually adding `mailBody` to the `mail` object before sending it. Is this just an cut and paste error in the question?

Comment: @JoséPedroBrito: Why not? What did you try? What problem did you have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You create an [`Attachment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment.aspx) and then add it to the `Attachments` collection:

```
// Create the attachment.
Attachment data = new Attachment(file, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
// Add the file attachment to this e-mail message.
message.Attachments.Add(data);
```

`file` is the pathname of the file you want to attach to the e-mail, as returned from your `FileSaveDialog`.

There's more that you might want to do, like adding time stamp information etc. and you need to call

```
data.Dispose();
```

after you've send the message.

As you are creating the file from code you can save it to a temporary directory and then delete it from disk once the e-mail has been sent without the user having to see a dialog or enter a file name.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.attachments.aspx)

You can create the attachment directly from memory by simply attaching a memory stream:

```
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    PdfWriter writertest = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, memoryStream);
    // Write contents of Pdf here

    // Set the position to the beginning of the stream.
    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    // Create attachment
    ContentType contentType = new ContentType();
    contentType.MediaType = MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf;
    contentType.Name = fileNameTextBox.Text;
    Attachment attachment = new Attachment(memoryStream, contentType);

    // Add the attachment
    message.Attachments.Add(attachment);

    // Send Mail via SmtpClient
    smtpClient.Send(message);
}
```

[Source](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21423/Creating-In-Memory-Mail-Attachments)

Comment: Hou can i put my pdf in that?

Comment: @JoséPedroBrito: Look at the constructors and static methods of the `Attachment` class.

Comment: @Chris: The file does not need to exist on disk.

Comment: @SLaks - OK - bad wording - I'll remove that.